# Ingone new line sign and space in typescript and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, newline

I am trying to match two sentence in protractor test. There is a new line in the second text. for this reason the two text is not getting matched in the test case.
I am getting this message from test output.

```
Expected 'Details user name role' to contain 'Details  user 
Name
Role
Linie 6'.
Expected :"Details  user\nName\nRole"   //extra space there
Actual   :"Details user Name Role"
```

my code is like this

```
await expect(detail.getText()).toContain('Details' + await users.get(user).getText());
```

how can avoid /n value from there. I want to get a plain text from this gettex method

Comment: `users.get(user).getText().replace(/\n/g, ' ')`

Comment: @Ionut. I tried you code, but the problem is there is an extra space. you see expected and actual. for that reason the test case still fails

Comment: You can use `trim()` for whitespaces. `users.get(user).getText().replace(/\n/g, ' ').trim()`. Although, I would check from where that whitespace's coming from and fix it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign original variable to temporary variable and then replace new line with " ".

Let's say your variable is,

```
  var text =  "Details  user\nName\nRole";
```

then,

```
   text.replace("\n"," ");    //This will result "Details  user Name Role"
```

Further,
You can check whether particular text contains new lines,

```
   text.includes("\n")k // true or false
```

[image]